# How to count the number of contiguous blocks of cells, each block comprising of the same row values?

Tags: google-sheets, countif

In Google Sheets, I have a sheet with a list of customers.
Row 1 has headers, and data starts in row 2.
Column A is Customer name,
Column B is street address,
Column C is City and Post Code,
Column D is Country.

I would like to count the number of occurrences of each customer's row, i.e. when A, B, C, D are the same as a composite key.

However, I want to count different occurrences of a row ONLY IF those occurrences are not adjacent / concurrent, i.e.
I do want to count separate occurrences if row 5 and 7 have the same customer,
but not if row 5 and 6 have the same customer...in this case I will count it as one occurrence

Sample sheet (`Customers`) with examples:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J7WajZjJfl94tpgXXgk0y5ALCwG2PxoJw6poxwUyrU8/edit?usp=sharing
I have added explanations for counts in column N.

Comment: Include you example sheet to make it easy for respondents.

Comment: Are you going to require comparison of just values in A or comparison of the whole row? (It doesn't change existing answers. But it changes the suitable question title.) Aside, do consider making genearlized titles and use generic terms so the q&a can be of use for others. For example, instead of "record", which is specific to your application, write "row" or "cell value" instead

Comment: @Argyll Whole row. I didn't say row because the the record consists only of a certain number of items and doesn't span the whole row; moreover the count has to be inserted in the row, so I didn't want to sow confusion. But if you think row is appropriate, I'll put row. Please confirm.

Comment: @OC2PS: I think row is better than cell in the title. It is clear now. Hope the 2 existing answers help you solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Say for example, you want to know the number of contiguous blocks whose column A value equals "O2 Arena", you can do

```
=countifs(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>A3:A),"="&A5)
```

It works because we want to omit rows where the value in column A is repeated in the next row. In other words, we keep those with different values than their next rows. Hence, `A2:A<>A3:A`.

---

If you want a list of counts for unique blocks, I recommend setting up the a list of the unique values first, ie. say in another sheet's A1, you have

```
=unique(Customers!A2:A)
```

then in B1, you can do

```
=countif(FILTER(Customers!$A$2:$A,Customers!$A$2:$A<>Customers!$A$3:$A),"="&A1)
```

and spread the above formula by double clicking the square on the lower right when you select B1.

The ranges in `filter()` should be absolute because the location of your data does not change. The range in the 2nd input of `countif()` should be relative because that is meant to iterate.

If values in column A does not uniquely identify your customers, you can add more columns to the input of `filter()` as required. For example, `FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>A3:A,B2:B<>B3:B)`

---

For function usage, please consult [official documentation](https://support.google.com/docs#topic=1382883) by typing the function name in the search bar.